# Azure Resource Provider register

Tags: azure

I have some problem. I am trying to register provider Microsoft.Web in my Microsoft Azure. I have a free trial.
I tried first method using the main panel in my account( subscription->Resource Providers->. I found Microsoft.Web from the list and clicked register, waited 10 seconds ant then error occured:

> The request timed out. Diagnostic information: timestamp
>   '20180904T134521Z', subscription id '', tracking id
>   '25a3c9a0-04dd-44d5-8fc8-1117820970d5', request correlation id
>   '25a3c9a0-04dd-44d5-8fc8-1117820970d5'. (Code: ServerTimeout)

Then I tried to use Azure ClI. I logged in to my account. I typed command:

> az provider register -n Microsoft.Web

It took like 10 minutes and then a long list of red errors showed up.
It begins with this:

> Error occurred in request., RetryError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url:
>   /subscriptions/9662cfad-f605-4262-aa76-c98891e4d88a/providers/Microsoft.Web/register?api-version=2018-05-01
>   (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses',))

Comment: There is an Azure Resource Monitor outage right now, so managing your subscription most probably won't work. Just wait until it's gone. You can check on its status here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: Agreed w/@Arion. Unfortunately nothing that can get resolved here on Stack Overflow. You can also the AzureSupport twitter account, which has been posting status updates.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help lads.

Comment: @Joe You may want to try again now.  I had this same exact issue for the past 2 hours or so for Microsoft.CognitiveServices, but it's working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We are currently experiencing an outage in South Central US
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/
[image]

You will want to monitor the Azure Status Page for further updates.